# Opencv ONNX support

Tags: opencv, onnx

I was trying to import one of the following models from the ONNX github page:

> https://github.com/onnx/models/tree/master/vision/object_detection_segmentation/mask-rcnn
>   https://github.com/onnx/models/tree/master/vision/object_detection_segmentation/faster-rcnn

with the function readNetFromONNX(). In Visual Studio just throws an exception and cannot load the models properly.

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF9A86300F6 (opencv_world420.dll) in inferenceONNX.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000022D857CFD6FD.
>   Exception thrown at 0x00007FF9A86300F6 (opencv_world420.dll) in inferenceONNX.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000022D857CFD6FD.

My version of opencv is 4.2.0 and the onnx models have a 1.5 version. What am I doing wrong? Should I upgrade to 4.3.0 version?

Thank you for your attention

The code, if helps:

```
 std::string onnxFile = "model/faster_rcnn_R_50_FPN_1x.onnx";  Not working
//std::string onnxFile = "model/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_1x.onnx"; Not working
//std::string onnxFile = "model/resnet34v1.onnx"; Loads correctly, v1.2.1

// Load the network
cv::dnn::Net net = cv::dnn::readNetFromONNX(onnxFile);
```

Comment: How did you solve this problem?